# What's wrong with my C program? It's about pointer and selection sort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, selection-sort

What's wrong with my C program? the title is to sort n number from small to large, when i run it, everything goes fine but the number isn't been sorted. I just don't know how to solve that although i have thought for a long time.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void selection(int *a[], int n);
int main()
{
    int n;
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *a[n];
    int b[n];
    srand((int) time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b[i] = ((int) (rand() % 100));
        a[i] = &b[i];
    }
    selection(a, n);
    return 0;
}

void selection(int *a[], int n)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int position;
    int temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        position = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (*a[i] > *a[j])
                position = j;
        }
        temp = *a[i];
        *a[i] = *a[position];
        *a[position] = temp;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        printf("%d\n", *a[i]);
}
```

Comment: is the code really about quicksort?

Comment: Why are you asking for `quicksort` and your function name is `bubble`... o.O

Comment: @Junsong Huang  There is no the quick sort, nor the bubble sort. I think there is the selection sort that is written incorrectly.:)

Comment: @JunsongHuang when you say `quicksort`, you mean `qsort` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found neither the quick sort nor the bubble sort in the presented code.

It seems you are trying to use the selection sort.

I think that the function can look the following way.

```
void selection_sort( int * a[], int n )
{
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        int position = i;
        int j = i + 1;

        for ( ; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if ( *a[j] < *a[position] ) position = j;
        }

        if ( position != i )
        {
            int *temp = a[position];
            a[position] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", *a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! it's my problem about the pointer. So can i think that i should exchange the address rather than the value, if i exchange the value, because the address isn't changed, when doing 'printf', the value won't be changed.

Comment: @JunsongHuang It seems you are trying to sort the array of pointers according to the criteria that one value pointed to by one pointer is less than the value pointed to by another pointer. That is the original array of values is not changed. It is the array of pointers to the elements of the original array that is changed.